# git cvsexportcommit destination branch

Tags: git, cvs

I am stuck using cvs. I want to work locally with git. I have had success using 'git cvsimport' to pull changes into git. I now have a git commit I would like to put back on a cvs branch.

I am looking at running the command:

```
git cvsexportcommit -v <commit-sha1>
```

I am confused as to what cvs branch this will commit to? How can I specify the destination branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exports to a CVS **work directory** so if it commits (-c flag) it calls `cvs commit` and does whatever CVS would normally do in that CVS work directory. (IIRC HEAD or whatever the *sticky flags* say)

(Edit; I suppose this is actually an answer, not just a comment)